# Фреймворк PHP нужен ли?

Tags: framework, php

Здравствуйте, сколько программирую на php, не разу не использовал в этой среде фреймворк. Мне хотелось узнать для оптимизации лучше использовать чистый код или использовать фреймворк. Хотелось поинтересоваться, есть ли отличия от обычного кода, кто может расскажите, буду рад адекватному ответу.
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: А можно глянуть на код какого-нибудь из ваших проектов, где все написано *самостоятельно?*

Comment: Вам скрипт скинуть? Он не влазит влазит в комментария =))

Comment: http://46.118.80.157/88/ вот пример календарь не давно писал, не очень симпатичен, но всеже). В основе мои проекты находятся в архивах.

Comment: Ну, вы хотя бы фильтруете входные данные. У вас есть все шансы стать хорошим специалистом.

Comment: Спасибо, стараюсь)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Любой фреймворк - это, в первую очередь, набор стандартов которые знают разработчики. Вокруг популярных фреймворков собирается серьезное сообщество разработчиков, а значит легко подключить или заменить человека в команде работающей над проектом.

Плюс, комьюнити создает массу готовых сторонних решений.

Answer (score 14):

Почти любой фреймворк создан с целью ускорить разработку, поддержку.
Скорости работы приложения это, при прочих равных, не добавляет.
Правда, учитывая что многие люди пишут резко неоптимальный код, те же действия на фреймворке срабатывают быстрее и чище.

Answer (score 5):

Фреймворк позволяет не изобретать велосипеды, иметь удобный доступ к базе (DAO), и гибкость. Я бы советовал начать с Code Igniter (по нему много документации на русском). 
Хотелось бы также отметить MVC-подход в фреймворках. Он позволяет без особого труда изменить/добавить тему оформления сайта и т.д.

Comment: А если не использовать фреймворк,я много потеряю?

Comment: Вы потеряете время и возможно удовольствие от комфортного программирования. Можно забивать гвозди молотком, а можно пассатижами. И то, и другое прекрасно справляется с задачей. Но молотком — приятнее и проще...

Comment: @Node_pro, при разработке более-менее крупных проектов ты потеряешь время изобретая велосипед (свой фреймворк) систематизирующий большие объемы кода.

Comment: "Можно забивать гвозди молотком, а можно..." - дальше я думал будет пневмопистолет, ну да ладно, пассатижи так пассатижи ))

Comment: @nMike, Ваша аналогия, разумеется, удачнее. Спасибо за отзыв :)